# Trying to inflate a PopupWindow outside MainActivity

Tags: java, android, popupwindow

I'm trying to inflate a PopupWindow outside the MainActivity class. I am able to inflate it inside the MainActivity but I'm getting the following error when I try to do it outside of it.

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main E/AndroidRuntime(7820):
>   android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window --
>   token null is not valid; is your activity running?

The following method works in MainActivity:

```
public void popUp() {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater 
    = (LayoutInflater)this
    .getSystemService(MyGameActivity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
    View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.gameover, null);  
    PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
            popupView, 
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);  
    popupWindow.showAtLocation(popupView, 0, 87, 120);
}
```

The method below is the one I'm trying to use outside the MainActivity class (this one gives the error):

```
public void popUp(Context context) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater 
    = (LayoutInflater)context
    .getSystemService(MyGameActivity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
    View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.gameover, null);  
    PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
            popupView, 
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);  
    popupWindow.showAtLocation(popupView, 0, 87, 120);
}
```

Any idea how I can this PopupWindow to work outside of my MainActivity?

--- Edit

LogCat result:

```
03-30 19:53:18.596: W/dalvikvm(8437): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d560)
03-30 19:53:18.596: E/AndroidRuntime(8437): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-30 19:53:18.596: E/AndroidRuntime(8437): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
03-30 19:53:18.596: E/AndroidRuntime(8437):     at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:533)
03-30 19:53:18.596: E/AndroidRuntime(8437):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
03-30 19:53:18.596: E/AndroidRuntime(8437):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
03-30 19:53:18.596: E/AndroidRuntime(8437):     at android.widget.PopupWindow.invokePopup(PopupWindow.java:907)
03-30 19:53:18.596: E/AndroidRuntime(8437):     at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAtLocation(PopupWindow.java:767)
03-30 19:53:18.596: E/AndroidRuntime(8437):     at nl.saxion.act.playground.GameView.popUp(GameView.java:314)
03-30 19:53:18.596: E/AndroidRuntime(8437):     at nl.saxion.act.playground.GameView.movePlayerLeft(GameView.java:299)
03-30 19:53:18.596: E/AndroidRuntime(8437):     at nl.saxion.act.playground.MyGameActivity$1.onClick(MyGameActivity.java:93)
03-30 19:53:18.596: E/AndroidRuntime(8437):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)
03-30 19:53:18.596: E/AndroidRuntime(8437):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)
03-30 19:53:18.596: E/AndroidRuntime(8437):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-30 19:53:18.596: E/AndroidRuntime(8437):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-30 19:53:18.596: E/AndroidRuntime(8437):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-30 19:53:18.596: E/AndroidRuntime(8437):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
03-30 19:53:18.596: E/AndroidRuntime(8437):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-30 19:53:18.596: E/AndroidRuntime(8437):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-30 19:53:18.596: E/AndroidRuntime(8437):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
03-30 19:53:18.596: E/AndroidRuntime(8437):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
03-30 19:53:18.596: E/AndroidRuntime(8437):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In here :

```
context = MyGameActivity.getContext(); //<<
```

this is not  right way to get Context of Activity in non Activity class(in normal java class). you just need to create `popUp()` with context parameter and pass Activity context to `popUp()` method from Activity as:

```
public void popUp(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    /....your code here
}
```

and call `popUp` method from MainActivity by passing context as:

```
popUpClass popObj=new popUpClass();
popObj.popUp(MainActivity.this);
```

Comment: I've tried the above but I'm still getting the same fatal exception. LogCat also points to the following line of code:   popupWindow.showAtLocation(popupView, 0, 87, 120); Any chance this could cause the problem?

Comment: @Johan : if still getting issue then plz add logcat result with question and also latest code

Comment: LogCat added after using your suggestion.

Comment: @Johan : what parameter you are passing in popUp() when calling it from Activity?

Comment: mGameView.popUp(MyGameActivity.this);

Comment: That does seem to fix the fatal exception, but the PopupWindow isn't showing now.

Comment: @Johan : now what problem u are getting any log?

Comment: No I'm not getting any log, the popupWindow simply isnt becoming visibile now. I've put a log.d at the start and the end the of the popUp method and both messages are printed in LogCat. That means the method is executed without any problems right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27245/discussion-between-johan-and--k)

Answer (score 0):

In your second method

```
 MyGameActivity.getContext();
```

refers to the static method that holds an instance of your `MyGameActivity` class. This is a very bad idea.

Indeed, you should understand, and it takes time at the beginning, that Android Activities or Fragments, Contexts in general, have a life cycle. This means that once they have been stopped, they should not be used any more. This would have 2 side-effets :

- you prevent this instance from being garbage collected as you hold a reference to it, thus polluting memory.
- this context can't be used and using it can, and will, create bugs related to memory leaks, dialog leaks, etc.

So, don't use your second method. It has no meaning to keep a reference on an activity when it has been closed.

The solution here is to add the first method in every activity that would need it, or put it in a common super class. Then it will always be related to the "current/vivid" instance of the activity class.

An alternative would be to provide you method a context and always pass it current active activity.

---BTW

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater 
= (LayoutInflater)this
.getSystemService(MyGameActivity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

can be written :

```
LayoutInflated.from( this );
```